# In Tableau, is it possible to customise linked tooltips?

Tags: tooltip, tableau-api, visualization

I'm creating a data visualisation on a chess set which contains details of the outcomes of chess games. I'm trying to use tooltips to display certain information: like in this instance I have a tooltip which shows me the likelihood of a certain colour winning a match when a certain opening move is played.

The tooltip is written like: 'The < Opening Name > ends in a win for < Winner > in < % of Total CNT(Games) > of games.'. However, when I hover over an area of my graph that shows a draw it obviously gives me a grammatically incorrect answer - 'The Indian Game ends in a win for Draw in 6.63% of games'. Is there a way to customise a specific tooltip so as not to affect the others? Or can I set a separate tooltip for the scenario in which a game ends in a draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a new calculated field in the data/sheet which may be calculated on

```
If [game result] = 'draw' 
THEN 'end in draw' 
ELSE 'end in'+ sum[wins] + 'wins'
END
```

condition.

Thereafter include that field in view on `details` marks card, so that it can be included in tooltip as per taste.